# how to do server side routing programmatically in react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using *react-router-dom* in my *react* project.

I am trying to **programmatically** navigate to a new parameter using: `history.push("/newparam")`

But the problem is navigating like this, isn't refreshing my page. Looks like its doing **fake client**
 side routing. But I want to refresh my browser when I am navigating programmatically.

So how can I do something like a **server-side** routing  using *react-router-dom*, where the page will refresh when the site will change url?

Comment: `React` is for single page applications. I am wondering why you want to refresh the page if you can do it without refreshing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use react-router the complete routing is handled by the react on client side, So the server is responsible to only load the index of the frontend application, This is a normal behavior in Single page application. We do all the communication with the server using XHR calls. Using `history.push("/newparam")` or `<Link route='/newparam' />` is always going to load the page from client side.

I dont exactly know what your usecase, But if you want the page to reload every time you navigate to a new page, use html `<a>` tag, This will initiate server side rendering. The JS equivalent of this would be `window.location.href = '/your-redirect-url';`

Let me know what exactly is your use-case so that I can help you further